# Get value when click in chart `area` type using ApexChart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, apexcharts

Hello i want ask about apexchart.
i want get specific value when i click in chart

i have apexchart like this :

```
    seriesku = [
                    {
                        name: 'Actual',
                        data: this.data.mystorage.map(data => {
                            return {
                                x: data.year,
                                y: data.actual
                            }
                        }),
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Target',
                        data: this.data.mystorage.map(data => {
                            return {
                                x: data.year,
                                y: data.budget
                            }
                        }),
                    },
                ]
return {
      chart: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    events: {
dataPointSelection: function (event, chartContext, config) {
var seriesData = chartContext.w.config.series[config.seriesIndex];
var dataPoint = seriesData.data[config.dataPointIndex];
console.log(seriesData.name);
console.log(dataPoint.x);
console.log(dataPoint.y);


                        }
                    }
                },
series =seriesku
}
```

i want get value using dataPointSelection and  it worked in chart type bar.
But what I really want is to use chart area type and using this code not worked, i dont see any error and any event when using the same code in area type.

in the chart area when I click on the actual value it automatically clicks on the target data too because they are in the same year. i think because of that dataPointSelection is not working ?
I don't have a problem with that condition, instead i want to get both the actual and target data for that year.

Can anyone help me ?